# How to open a link with multiple choices in an Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I saw on the Discord application that as soon as we open a link, the application asks us to choose our browser if we have several.

Then the web page is displayed with a toolbar. In this toolbar there is a cross on the left to return to the application. I imagine some kind of WebView.

**Does anyone know how to do this in Java for an Android app or tutorial I can't find anything similar on the internet**

Answer (score 0):

That's not the webView.....Intent is passed into your web browser so that Link is redirected
call your button listener inside that

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(yourURI));
        context.startActivity(i);
```